# rclone copy symlinks as symlinks

Tags: symbolic-link, rclone

I would like to use rclone to copy one local disk drive to another disk drink. Attempting:

```sh
rclone /Volumes/diska /Volumes/diskb
```

This fails with `Can't follow symlink without -L/--copy-links`.

The disk contents includes Final Cut Pro projects which naturally use symlinks as part of the project files.

So I'd like to copy the contents verbatim, including these necessary symlinks in full fidelity. And if I can use rclone then I can use the some tool for other stuff.

The recommended option `--copy-links` seems to copy the *contents* of the symlink, not what I want. Is there another way to actually copy as a symlink?

Answer (score 6):

The --links flag tells Rclone to copy symbolic links as symbolic links instead of copying the files that the symbolic links point to. In other words, it makes Rclone maintain the symbolic link structure of the source directory when copying to the destination.

Use `rclone --links [blah blah your other args here]`

I.E. `rclone --links /Volumes/diska /Volumes/diskb` in your case

When you run "man rclone", you'll find the following line:

```
-l, --links    Translate symlinks to/from regular files with a '.rclonelink' extension
```

Comment: (The `--links` option has only been implemented for local backend as of yet..)